# questions about If function

Tags: programming, conditional

The following is a part of my codes.

codes:

`If[IsABeforeB[y1[[2]], y2[[2]], l] == 0, 
   ( r = r + CommutatorOne[y1, y2, q1, q2, c, y, s, s1];
    L1 = InterchangeAandB[i, i + 1, L1];
    i = 1;
    ),
   i = i + 1;
   ]];`

If `IsABeforeB[y1[[2]], y2[[2]], l] == 0`, then we do

`( r = r + CommutatorOne[y1, y2, q1, q2, c, y, s, s1];
    L1 = InterchangeAandB[i, i + 1, L1];
    i = 1;
 ),`

I wrote the three lines inside a bracket (). If `IsABeforeB[y1[[2]], y2[[2]], l] != 0`, then let  `i = i + 1;` Is the  syntax of the codes correct? Can we use () here? Thank you very much.

The complete codes is in the following.

`IndexOfAnElement[a_, l_] := (
   r = 0;
   For[i = 1, i <= Length[l], i++, 
    (If[a == l[[i]],
      (r = i; Break[])] 
     )];
   Return[r]);`

`IsABeforeB[a_, b_, l_] := ( 
   i = IndexOfAnElement[a, l];
   j = IndexOfAnElement[b, l];
   r = 0;
   If[i <= j, 
    r = 1; r = 0
    ]; 
   Return[r]);`


`exponentNew[a_[b__]^c_] := c;
exponentNew[a_[b__]] := 1;
exponentNew[a_^c] := c;
exponentNew[a_] := 1;`


`headNew[a_[b__]^c_] := a;
headNew[a_[b__]] := a;
headNew[a_^c] := a;
headNew[a_] := a;`


`Indices[a_[b__]^c_] := {b};
Indices[a_[b__]] := {b};
Indices[a_] := {};`

`InterchangeAandB[i_, j_, l_] := (
   r = l;
   temp = r[[i]];
   r[[i]] = r[[j]];
   r[[j]] = temp;
   Return[r]);`

`pthPowerNew[expr_, p_] := 
  Replace[expr, s_Symbol :> s^p, Infinity, Heads -> False];`

A test example is `pthPowerNew[(2+x)/(2*c+3), p]`

`CommutatorOne[l1_, l2_, q1_, q2_, c_, y_, s_, s1_] := (
   y1 = headNew[l1[[2]]];
   y2 = headNew[l2[[2]]];
   {i, p} = Indices[l1[[2]]];
   {j, p2} = Indices[l2[[2]]]; 
   r = 0;
   If[{y1, y2} == {y, s} && p != 0 && p2 != 0,
    r = l1[[1]]*l2[[1]]*(-1/p)*(1 - q1^p)*KroneckerDelta[p, -p2]*
      KroneckerDelta[i, j]];
   If[{y1, y2} == {s, y} &&  p != 0  &&  p2 != 0, 
    r = l1[[1]]*l2[[1]]*(1/p2)*(1 - q1^p2)*KroneckerDelta[p, -p2]*
      KroneckerDelta[i, j]];
   If[{y1, y2} == {s1, y} &&  p == 0  &&  p2 == 0, 
    r = l1[[1]]*l2[[1]]*(-1)*Log[q1]*KroneckerDelta[i, j]];
   If[{y1, y2} == {y, s1} &&  p == 0  &&  p2 == 0, 
    r = l1[[1]]*l2[[1]]*Log[q1]*KroneckerDelta[i, j]];
   If[{y1, y2} == {y, y} &&  p > 0, 
    r = l1[[1]]*l2[[1]]*(-1/p)*(1 - q1^p)*(1 - q2^p)*
      pthPowerNew[Inverse[c][[j]][[i]], -p]*KroneckerDelta[p, -p2]];
   If[{y1, y2} == {y, y} &&  p < 0, 
    r = l1[[1]]*l2[[1]]*(-1/p)*(1 - q1^(-p))*(1 - q2^(-p))*
      pthPowerNew[Inverse[c][[i]][[j]], p]*KroneckerDelta[p, -p2]];
   If[{y1, y2} == {s, s} &&  p > 0, 
    r = l1[[1]]*l2[[1]]*(-1/p)*(1 - q1^p)/(1 - q2^(-p))*
      pthPowerNew[c[[i]][[j]], p]*KroneckerDelta[p, -p2]];
   If[{y1, y2} == {s, s} &&  p < 0, 
    r = l1[[1]]*l2[[1]]*(1/p2)*(1 - q1^p2)/(1 - q2^(-p2))*
      pthPowerNew[c[[j]][[i]], p2]*KroneckerDelta[p, -p2]];
   If[{y1, y2} == {s1, s}, 
    r = l1[[1]]*l2[[1]]*(Log[q1]/Log[q2])*pthPowerNew[c[[i]][[j]], 0]*
      KroneckerDelta[0, p2]];
   If[{y1, y2} == {s, s1}, 
    r = -l1[[1]]*l2[[1]]*(Log[q1]/Log[q2])*pthPowerNew[c[[j]][[i]], 0]*
      KroneckerDelta[p, 0]];
   Return[r]);`

A test example is 
`CommutatorOne[{w1^(p)*x^(p), y[1, -p]}, {x1^p, 
  s[1, p]}, q1, q2, C1, y, s, s1]`

`Normalization[l1_, l2_, q1_, q2_, c_, y_, s_, s1_, l_] := (
   r = 0;
   L1 = Join[l1, l2];
   i = 1;
   While[i <= Length[L1] - 1,

    y1 = L1[[i]];
    y2 = L1[[i + 1]];
    If[IsABeforeB[y1[[2]], y2[[2]], l] == 0,
     ( r = r + CommutatorOne[y1, y2, q1, q2, c, y, s, s1];
      L1 = InterchangeAandB[i, i + 1, L1];
      i = 1;
      ),
     i = i + 1
     ]];
   r = Simplify[r];
   Return[r]);`

The function Normalization has some problems. A test example is

`Clear[y, s, s1, q1, q2];
l = {y[1, -p], s[1, -p], y[1, 0], s[1, 0], s1[1, 0], y[1, p], s[1, p]}; 
p = 7; 
q = q1*q2; 
C1 = {{1 + 1/(q1 q2), -(mu/(q1 q2))}, {-(1/mu), 1 + 1/(q1 q2)}};
T1 = {{w1^(p)*x^(p), y[1, -p]}, {w2^p*x^p, y[1, -p]}, {2, 
   y[1, 0]}, {x^(-p)*w1^(-p), y[1, p]}, {x^(-p)*w2^(-p), y[1, p]}}; 
T2 = {{x1^p, s[1, -p]}, {Log[x1], s[1, 0]}, {1, s1[1, 0]}, {x1^(-p), 
   s[1, p]}}; 
r1 = Normalization[T1, T2, q1, q2, C1, y, s, s1, l]`

Comment: Please include the rest of your code so I can replicate the semantics on my machine? For example the code for the function `IsABeforeB[a, b, c]` @Jianrong

Comment: @Conor Cosnett, thank you very much for your help. I include the rest of my codes. It is long. All functions are correct except the function Normalization.

Comment: @Conor Cosnett, 

Clear[y, s, s1, q1, q2];

l = {y[1, -p], s[1, -p], y[1, 0], s[1, 0], s1[1, 0], y[1, p], s[1, p]} 

p = 7 

q = q1*q2 

C1 = {{1 + 1/(q1 q2), -(mu/(q1 q2))}, {-(1/mu), 1 + 1/(q1 q2)}}

T1 = {{w1^(p)*x^(p), y[1, -p]} } 

T2 = {{x1^p, s[1, -p]} } 

r1 = Normalization[T1, T2, q1, q2, C1, y, s, s1, l]

is a test example. The result should be 0.

Comment: Please format and explain your code more. @Jianrong. I have a headache now but I will try to understand it tomorrow.

Comment: @ConorCosnett, thank you very much. I edited the codes.

Comment: I'm sorry but the complexity is too much for me. (Are you trying to fix your `Normalisation` function?): If so, I highly recommend making a very simple example of your `Normalization` function. Make a new question with just that function. Include the input and output that you expect from the function. @Jianrong

Comment: @Conor Cosnett, thank you very much for your suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

here is the syntax for a successful `If`.

Make sure you put in 2 commas!

```
If[
     a == b,

    (stuff;
     if;
     true),


   (stuff;
    if;
    false)


   ]
```